# Phalcon join multiple database in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phalcon

Usually in SQL or Codeigniter's Active record we can join 2 different database tables in
single query like:

```
join database_1.table_1 on ..
join database_2.table_2 on ..
```

How do we achieve this is "Phalcon"?

I tried to do it, but got an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'database_2.table_2' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Phalcon's query builder](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder.html)

Specifically:

```
<?php

$builder->join('Robots');
$builder->join('Robots', 'r.id = RobotsParts.robots_id');
$builder->join('Robots', 'r.id = RobotsParts.robots_id', 'r');
$builder->join('Robots', 'r.id = RobotsParts.robots_id', 'r', 'LEFT');
```

OR Left joins:

```
<?php

$builder->leftJoin('Robots', 'r.id = RobotsParts.robots_id', 'r');
```

etc.